# Realtime HTTP notifications using Google Analytics when user views my page?

Tags: http, google-analytics, real-time

I was wondering if its possible with Google Analytics to send real-time HTTP notifications to say PHP when a user visits my website. If not, I am curious about any real-time notifications that Google Analytics can send to me when a user visits my site. Thanks!

EDIT::Just came across [Piwik](http://www.piwik.org) and it says that it is realtime... does anyone have any experience with them or using their api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no. You'll have to use another service or write your own.

Maybe there is a commercial google analytics that may give you this but i don't know.

Comment: Hmmm, do you have any experience with Piwik? It says it is realtime but I am wondering if it can do what I am asking.

Comment: You should start a new question!

Answer (score 0):

Just to announce that this feature is very close to be released.

According to their blog (http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html), it will become public sometime in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

too late but, you can use imrelay - for free http://indo-mars.com/imrelay/ , just use socket.io /webrtc in your php.